# Android emulator error

Tags: android, android-emulator, bitmap, android-2.2-froyo

I have successfully executed a project in a system,with Android 2.2...

When i ran the project in other system,with same configuration and emulator options,it crashes...

The error log says:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myabc/com.myabc.Screen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class

Can anybody provide me with a solution for this,as its a serious one for the application to be debugged in some other system...

The xml im inflating is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/splashback" 
>
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/img6" android:src="@drawable/splash71" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_x="0dip" android:layout_y="0dip"></ImageView>
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/img5" android:src="@drawable/splash5" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_x="0dip" android:layout_y="0dip"></ImageView>
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/img4" android:src="@drawable/splash4" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_x="0dip" android:layout_y="0dip"></ImageView>
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/img3" android:src="@drawable/splash3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_x="0dip" android:layout_y="0dip"></ImageView>
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/img2" android:src="@drawable/splash2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_x="0dip" android:layout_y="0dip"></ImageView>
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/img1" android:src="@drawable/splash1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_x="0dip" android:layout_y="0dip"></ImageView>
 <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/img0" android:src="@drawable/screen8" android:layout_x="0dp" android:layout_y="0dp"></ImageView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

The complete stack trace says :

```
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myabc/com.myabc.Screen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at com.myabc.Screen.onCreate(Screen.java:29)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  ... 11 more
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  ... 22 more
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
04-01 10:41:57.475: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:118)
```

Comment: post the xml you are inflating

Comment: @Akhil- inflated XML and complete stack trace are added...pls help buddies...

Comment: @alextsc inflated XML and complete stack trace are added...pls help buddies...

Comment: First thing AbsoluteLayout is depreciated would be better if you use any other layout share the complete xml file that is inflating also code snippet how you are inflating in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are getting `OutOfMemoryError:bitmap size exceeds VM budget`. It seems that the bitmaps you are trying to use for ImageViews are taking huge amounts of memory. It is best if you keep lighter image files (scale them down by lowering resolution) at location from where you are getting your images. One less preferred way is to compress images one by one in memory and recycle() every time.

```
 private static Bitmap codec(Bitmap src, Bitmap.CompressFormat format,
                                    int quality) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            src.compress(format, quality, os);

            byte[] array = os.toByteArray();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);
        }
```

See this example at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CreateBitmap.html

Comment: The image size,which are used in the application development should be precisely designed,considering the size..........thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

You are using too much memory. Reduce the resolution of your pictures *(by scaling the image files; not by changing the imageview size)* within the layout and try again.

Also please *never* use AbsoluteLayout, it's deprecated and you will run into trouble on many devices.

Comment: The image size,which are used in the application development should be precisely designed,considering the size..........thanks

Answer (score 2):

First thing AbsoluteLayout is depreciated would be better if you use any other layout share the complete xml file that is inflating also code snippet how you are inflating in code.

Comment: Layout is just secondary...if it is deprecated also,the virtual machine should inflate it...but i am able to run in the system,where the application was originally started developing....

Comment: As suggest by @Akhil  what is you image size share the code snippet also

Comment: The image size is comparitively medium,but i hav to load about 7 images at a time...will that be the problem?

Comment: The image size,which are used in the application development should be precisely designed,considering the size..........thanks for the help......